# How do I center content and have a footer using Bootstrap4 and/or flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Please see the following code. I just want to center content with a footer that appears at the bottom, all of which is inside a background cover image. I've tried doing this with Bootstrap4 containers as well as d-flex configurations, all of which has been an abysmal fail. :(

Presently I'm using two columns that are stacked on top of each other but it doesn't work when you make the screen smaller in height. I'm hoping for the proper way to do this by actually centering content using the entire screen while maintaining a footer.

Also see here for a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m05heusn/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

      <title>t-rex</title>

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- bootstrap4 css should load first to be available globally -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js" integrity="sha384-vGq6VlJ/rGDK5hwCZhgtrb5j4nOanwgWgBSe9anrJGQHqCgkBo45u6lAxlVR0U+Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <style>
        html,
        body {
          font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
          height: 100%;
        }

        #cover {
          background-attachment: scroll;
          background-image: url('http://source.unsplash.com/9euUL1nE9aA/1920x1080');
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: cover;
        }
      </style>

      <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xyz"></script>
      <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'xyz');
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light afixed-top py-4">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            t-rex
          </a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div> <!-- navMenu -->
        </div> <!-- container -->
      </nav>

      <div id="cover" class="h-100">

        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
          <div class="row h-100 text-center">
            <div class="col-12 align-self-center text-center">
              <div class="display-1 d-none d-sm-block">
                t-rex
              </div>

              <div class="display-3 d-block d-sm-none">
                t-rex
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 align-self-end p-2">
              <div class="d-none d-sm-block text-right">
                Copyright &copy; 2018 t-rex. All rights reserved.
              </div>

              <div class="small d-block d-sm-none text-center">
                Copyright &copy; 2018 t-rex. All rights reserved.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- cover


      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js " integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>

      <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js " integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script> -->

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49 "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>

      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate, what are you trying to achieve? I see that there are two copyright blocks at the bottom. What do you want to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

In this code block there is "text-right" class:

```
<div class="d-none d-sm-block text-right">Copyright &copy; 2018 t-rex. All rights reserved.</div>
```

So, change it to "text-center".